# Cannot fetch parse.com relation from object php

Tags: php, parse-platform

I'm using the PHP parse.com SDK to get some data from the server, but whenever I try to do the `$query->find()` nothing happens.

```
    $historyDB = new ParseObject('History', $historyId);
    $relation = $historyDB->getRelation("exams");
    $query = $relation->getQuery();
    $findQuery = $query->find();
```

My `$findQuery` variable whenever I try to `print_r()` it shows this error:

```
    exception 'Parse\ParseException' with message 'missing class name' in 
    C:\wamp\www\parse\php-sdk\src\Parse\ParseClient.php:297 Stack trace: #0 
    C:\wamp\www\parse\php-sdk\src\Parse\ParseQuery.php(346):
    Parse\ParseClient::_request('GET', '/1/classes/?whe...', NULL, NULL, false) #1
    C:\wamp\www\report.php(110): Parse\ParseQuery->find() #2 {main}
```

I have no idea why,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: IMHO it makes no sense to use such a service. You see, it isn't simpler, it is more complicated that way. Also a developer should take himself on the most important part: The data.

Comment: But what you are going to get?The ParseRelation object just need a **$targetClassName** to get the result by making a  Parse API Call request.So just read the official document.

Comment: I have actually read the official documente but I have not found anything about setting the **$tagetClassName**. I have read it from [here](https://parse.com/docs/php/guide#queries-relational-queries). Imma definitely write this down now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the **targetClassName** property of the **ParseRelation** object before you call getQuery(),try to set it by calling setTargetClass().

```
$historyDB = new ParseObject('History', $historyId);
$relation  = $historyDB->getRelation("exams");
$relation->setTargetClass('targetClassName');
$query     = $relation->getQuery();
$findQuery = $query->find();
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Parse really need to update its documentation.